# Why is this question not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates, dnd-5e

This question:

[Do Forgotten Realms paladins have to follow a deity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153477/do-forgotten-realms-paladins-have-to-follow-a-deity)

references this other question:

[Are paladins required to follow a god?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51805/are-paladins-required-to-follow-a-god)

asking what seems to be the same question. Why is it not a duplicate? The implication seems to be that unofficial [tweets](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2019/04/24/does-a-paladin-need-to-serve-a-god-deity/) can override an official source (the PHB), and thus that the newer question is somehow not answered by the previous question.

(I would vote to close, but I do not appear to have that option.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I have stated - I am looking for published source material for the Forgotten Realms in 5e that would support the unofficial assertion of a designer that FR paladins (as opposed to run of the mill 5e paladins) do in fact have to have a deity.

The question is not a duplicate as it is looking for information about the Forgotten Realms setting in 5e, not the already answered question about 5e generically.

Comment: Aren't more general versions of questions considered to be duplicates like this one here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151000

Comment: @Medix2 I don't think I am asking the same question. 5e paladin requirements vs forgotten realms 5e paladin requirements. From what you linked : "questions should only be marked as a duplicate if they are asking the same thing" I don't think it is asking the same thing.

Comment: I guess to me if a specific exception existed for FR it should be mentioned in answers to the other question. But perhaps I'm unusual in that belief.

Comment: As a setting-specific question it is meaningfully distinct enough from the generic question of what the rules say, especially with the additional context of there being confusing/conflicting statements about whether or not this detail is different from sources that could reasonably be considered authorities on the setting.

Comment: @Medix2 Settings often override default D&D details.

Comment: Forgotten Realms is the default setting of 5e.

Comment: @Raj only for the modules, not the core books.

Comment: @Raj https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45584/3958

Comment: @Medix2 There is no agreement I know of, and certainly no guarantee, that answers to general questions have chased down all conceivable edge cases and exceptions, and noted them all.  The only way to know is to ask, and in that case, you have a new question.

Comment: I now understand that these are different questions, thank you to the people telling me so and providing evidence to that fact